# difference between Double.valueOf and doubleValue

Tags: java

```
double displayNumber = Double.valueOf(display.getText()).doubleValue()
```

please explain me the uses and the need of .valueOf and .doubleValue in this statement.

Comment: Javadoc is there for a reason.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @SawtìkTítåmGàñgùlý: The first step in learning to program is to learn how to read documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Double.valueOf` returns a `Double` type, then calling `doubleValue()` gives you primitive double type. You can replace both the methods with `Double.parseDouble`

```
double displayNumber = Double.valueOf(display.getText()).doubleValue()
```

to

```
double displayNumber = Double.parseDouble(display.getText())
```

Comment: Also, you should take a look about [primitive type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and [primitive wrapper class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) in Java.

Comment: In case you got your answer you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I landed on this peice of code:

int decPlaces= (int)buttonText.charAt(0) - (int)'0';

please tell me the use of (int)'0' here. 
is it type casting?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't ask it as a separate question. Because for the last half an hour, i am unable to give a suitable title to this question , which this site accepts..!